# How to change text to textbox on clicking it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnVNc/) for changing the label's value by clicking on it.

But i don't want to do it while i click on the edit (href)

I just want to click on the name and change it to textbox and while i take the mouse outside it should change back to label

How can i do this ?

Here's the jquery code i have

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.edit').click(function () {
        var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
        dad.find('label').hide();
        dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();
    });

    $('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
        var dad = $(this).parent();
        $(this).hide();
        dad.find('label').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: you mean when you click outside you want to change it back or do you mean when you hover out of it then change it back?

Comment: Would you be ok with hiding the edit element on click?

Comment: @fauxerious : can i edit it by clicking on the name ?

Comment: I was figuring when you click edit, the edit text could disappear.  On focusout, it could reappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/fnVNc/497/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.control-label').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.edit-input').show();
    });

    $('.edit-input').focusout(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.control-label').text($(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the target of your click function from:

```
$('a.edit').click(function () {
```

to

```
$('.text-info').click(function () {
```

You could also add a hover function if you want the input to be hidden on mouseout rather than when clicking outside. For example:

```
$('input[type=text]').hover(function () {
}, function () {
    var dad = $(this).parent();
    $(this).hide();
    dad.find('label').show();
});
```

Here your adjusted [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnVNc/496/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with this modified version of the fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.control-label').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        var dad = $(this).parent();
        dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();
    });

    $('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
        var dad = $(this).parent();
        $(this).hide();
        dad.find('label').text(this.value).show();
    });
});
```

It doesn´t set the default value that was in the label before though.